Seeking Best Methods to Identify and Analyze Sharp Trends in Stocks and Currencies Using Python
I have basic proficiency in Python development and I'm interested in analyzing the relationship between certain parameters and sharp changes in stock and currency trends. What are the best methods for accurately identifying and marking these sharp trends for comparison with my parameters?
So far, I've tried marking maximum and minimum points over short periods, but this approach doesn't effectively highlight the ranges with the most significant fluctuations. I'm looking for familiar or creative solutions to better capture and analyze these sharp trends.

It might be helpful to be more specific about your problem, for example, what is the format of your data? What do you mean by sharp changes? How are you getting the trends data etc.?
